# universal media server on RasPi

Tags: raspbian, media-server

Regarding one of my previous questions about minidlna (found here [miniDLNA & srt files](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/23190/minidlna-srt-files))

I want to know If (an how) I can install UMS (Universal Media Server) on a raspi.
I also wonder if it can do the heavy lifting required.

Since my miniDLNA refused to stream .srt files with video I'm looking for an alternative.

Following this guide:
http://www.slsmk.com/how-to-install-universal-media-server-ums-on-ubuntu-in-headless-mode/

I run into the following problem when trying to do:

```
 #  update-rc.d UMS defaults

update-rc.d: using dependency based boot sequencing
insserv: script UMS is not an executable regular file, skipped!
insserv: Script UMS is broken: incomplete LSB comment.
insserv: missing `Provides:' entry: please add.
insserv: missing `Required-Start:' entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Required-Stop:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Default-Start:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Default-Stop:'   entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `UMS'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `UMS'
```

the config file:

nano /etc/init.d/UMS

```
#!/bin/bash
#
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          ums
# Required-Start:    $local_fs $remote_fs $network
# Required-Stop:     $local_fs $remote_fs $network
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Starts UMS program.
# Description:       Java Upnp Media Server
### END INIT INFO

#set -x

# Author: Papa Issa DIAKHATE 
#
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
DESC="Universal Media Server"
NAME=UMS
UMS_PROFILE=/etc/UMS.conf
DAEMON=/opt/ums/$NAME
DAEMON_OPTS="console"
SCRIPTNAME=/etc/init.d/$NAME
UMS_START=1 # Wether to start or not UMS ver at boot time.
DODTIME=30  # Time to wait for the server to die, in seconds.
            # If this value is set too low you might not
            # let the program to die gracefully and 'restart' will not work

test -x $DAEMON || exit 1

# Load the VERBOSE setting and other rcS variables
. /lib/init/vars.sh

# Define LSB log_* functions.
# Depend on lsb-base (>= 3.0-6) to ensure that this file is present.
. /lib/lsb/init-functions

# Include ums defaults if available
if [[ -f "/etc/default/$NAME" ]] ; then
        . /etc/default/$NAME
fi

# May we run the init.d script ?
[[ $UMS_START = 1 ]] || exit 1

#--------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Some color codes
txtred=$'\e[0;31m' # Red
txtylw=$'\e[0;33m' # Yellow
txtrst=$'\e[0m'    # Text Reset
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------
warnout(){
    echo >&2 -e ""$txtylw"Warning:$txtrst $1"
}
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------
running(){
    pid=`pgrep -f 'java .*ums.jar.*'`
}
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------
do_start(){
    running && { warnout "$NAME is already running !"; exit 0; }
    echo "Starting $DESC : $NAME"
    UMS_PROFILE="$UMS_PROFILE" start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --background --oknodo \
        --exec $DAEMON -- $DAEMON_OPTS

}
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------
do_stop(){
    running || { warnout "$NAME is NOT running !"; exit 0; }   
    local countdown="$DODTIME"
    echo -e "Stopping $DESC : $NAME \c "
    kill -9 $pid
    while running; do
        if (($countdown >= 0)); then
            sleep 1; echo -n .;
            ((--countdown))
        else
            break;
        fi
    done
    echo
    # If still running, then try to send SIGINT signal
    running && { \
        echo >&2 "Using kill -s SIGINT instead"; \
        echo >&2 "If you see this message again, then you should increase the value of DODTIME in '$0'."; \
        kill -2 $pid; \
    }

    if [ -e "/opt/ums/debug.log" ]; then
    count=9
    while [ $count -ge 1 ]
    do
    if [ -e "/opt/ums/debug.log.$count" ]; then
        plus=$((count+1))
        mv "/opt/ums/debug.log.$count" "/opt/ums/debug.log.$plus"
    fi
        count=$((count-1))
    done
    if [ -e "/opt/ums/debug.log" ]; then
        mv "/opt/ums/debug.log" "/opt/ums/debug.log.1"
    fi
    fi

    return 0
}
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------
do_force-stop(){
    running || { warnout "$NAME is NOT running !"; exit 0; }   
    echo "Stopping $DESC : $NAME"
    kill -9 $pid
    if [ -e "/opt/ums/debug.log" ]; then
    count=9
    while [ $count -ge 1 ]
    do
    if [ -e "/opt/ums/debug.log.$count" ]; then
        plus=$((count+1))
   mv "/opt/ums/debug.log.$count" "/opt/ums/debug.log.$plus"
    fi
       count=$((count-1))
    done
    if [ -e "/opt/ums/debug.log" ]; then
   mv "/opt/ums/debug.log" "/opt/ums/debug.log.1"
    fi
    fi
}
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------
do_status(){
    echo -n " * $NAME is "
    ( running || { echo "NOT running "; exit 0; } )
    ( running && { echo "running (PID -> $(echo $pid))"; exit 0; } )
}
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------
case "$1" in

    start|stop|force-stop|status)
        do_${1}
        ;;
    restart|reload)
        do_stop
        do_start
        ;;
    force-restart|force-reload)
        do_force-stop
        do_start
        ;;
    *)
        echo "Usage: $SCRIPTNAME {start|stop|force-stop|restart|force-restart|reload|force-reload|status}"
        exit 1
        ;;
esac
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logs make me think the startup script is not provided. To run `update-rc.d UMS defaults`, you have to provide such a script (in `/etc/init.d/`). Make sure the file `/etc/init.d/UMS` exists.

- ```
  insserv: script UMS is not an executable regular file, skipped!
  ```

  This line makes me think you have to make the script runnable. Run `sudo chmod a+x /etc/init.d/UMS` to make sure it has enough permissions to run.
- ```
  insserv: missing `Provides:' entry: please add.
  insserv: missing `Required-Start:' entry: please add even if empty.
  insserv: missing `Required-Stop:'  entry: please add even if empty.
  insserv: missing `Default-Start:'  entry: please add even if empty.
  insserv: missing `Default-Stop:'   entry: please add even if empty.
  ```

  You have to provide the following lines at the beginning of the startup script:

  ```
  ### BEGIN INIT INFO
  # Provides:          UMS
  # Required-Start:    $local_fs
  # Required-Stop:     $local_fs
  # Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
  # Default-Stop:      0 1 6
  # Short-Description: Start/stop UMS
  ### END INIT INFO
  ```
- ```
  insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `UMS'
  insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `UMS'
  ```

  You need the following code structure to run the script:

  ```
  case "$1" in
    start)
      # what to do to start UMS
      ;;
    stop)
      # what to do to start UMS
      ;;
    *)
      echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/UMS {start|stop}"
      exit 1
      ;;
  esac
  exit 0
  ```

Maybe a startup script already exists on your file system (try `ls /etc/init.d/ | grep universal` or `ls /etc/init.d/ | grep media` to find it), or on the Internet. Otherwise you will have to write your own (have a look [here](https://github.com/fhd/init-script-template), or [here](https://gist.github.com/naholyr/4275302))

Comment: # update-rc.d /etc/init.d/UMS defaults
update-rc.d: using dependency based boot sequencing
update-rc.d: error: unable to read /etc/init.d//etc/init.d/UMS

It has also been made runable, and I use the file provided in the turorial, that file conains th einit info header aswell...

Comment: also :
# ls -l /etc/init.d | grep UMS
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4830 Sep  9 12:24 UMS

Comment: @Havnar When I said "you have to provide such a script", I meant that `/etc/init.d/UMS` must exist. Not that you have to run `update-rc.d /etc/init.d/UMS defaults`. The command `update-rc.d UMS defaults` should be fine ;-)  So you have an init.d script... Make sure there are no leading space before the `#`s at the beginning of the file.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it were leading spaces before the #init info now it seems to work

Comment: I came home but noticed even though it doesn't throw errors, it doesn't seem to work

Comment: What does not work? The init.d script, or UMS? In the first case, try to run the startup script directly from your console (`cd /etc/init.d && ./UMS`)? In the second case, I would suggest to try out running UMS in you console in a standalone way to make sure the configuration is correct.

Comment: Both dont work... Service ums status returns nothing